# How to avoid duplicate usernames in database

Tags: php

I want check usernames in database against a new username.
If the a username is found, regenerate a username at least by a number
or a nice character attached to the firstname and lastname 
and check again if the new generated username also do not exist.

If it doesn't exists run a query to INSERT.

The reason why I want this is because I dont want a duplicate usernames
in database.

I tried but its not working for me
Please help.

```
<?php
    //check if username already exists

function checkusername($username){
    global $dbc_conn, $table_name;

    //CHECK IF A USERNAME EXISTS
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc_conn,"SELECT COUNT(username) FROM $table_name WHERE username ='{$username}'");
    $rows   =   mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    if(count($rows) > 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}



//This function create new account

function signup($fname, $lname , $regemail , $regpassword , $gender , $school , $day,$month,$year,$school){

    global $dbc_conn, $table_name;

    //CHECK IF EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc_conn,"SELECT Email FROM $table_name WHERE Email ='{$regemail}'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0 ){
        $error ="<div class='error'><strong> <i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> </strong>Sorry, It looks like you already have an account with us.</div>";

    }else{

        $username = strtolower($fname.$lname);

        //Check if username is do not exists, and if it exist
        while(checkusername($username)){
            //INSERT INTO DATABASE
            $query = "INSERT INTO users 
                            (username,FirstName,LastName,Email,
                             Password,Month,Day,Year,Gender,cell_group) 
                      VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            //PREPARE QUERY
            $prepare = $dbc_conn ->prepare($query);

            //BIND QUERY
            $prepare->bind_param("ssssssisis",$username,$fname, 
                                              $lname , $regemail , 
                                              md5($regpassword) , $gender , 
                                              $school , $day,
                                              $month,$year,$school);

            //execute requery
            if($prepare->execute()){

                //SET SESSION
                $_SESSION['usigh-ses'] = mysqli_insert_id($dbc_conn);
                header("location:gettingstarted.php");

               //close connection
                mysqli_close($dbc_conn);
                exit;       
            };
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how is it 'not working'.

Comment: Have it as a unique key then catch the exception

Comment: Since you are using COUNT, one row will always be returned, but the value will be 0 if there are no matching records. Better to just SELECT and check if any rows are returned

Comment: Compartmentalize your code into functions so it is easier to follow and understand. Also, I'm thinking your select statement here is breaking `SELECT COUNT(username) FROM $table_name WHERE username ='{$username}'"` Do you want the curly-brackets in here?

Comment: Adding a unique key will add better assurance that a username will never get duplicated, but you still need to handle the logic in your code so your queries don't just fail mysteriously

Comment: it's also unknown if the session was started and is relevant to the code's possible failure, since you are using a session array to redirect on a MySQL function.

Comment: A little less white space and a bit more inteligent code layout would help you do your own debugging

Comment: It makes me sad to see an SQL injection in the same block of code as a successful parameterised query :'c

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Maybe the parameters are already sanitized.. But I get your point :)

Comment: I think I have an error in my checkusername function...I want to rewrite the code and update it.

Comment: use a alias to count in your SELECT. o mysql_num_rows will aways return 1. You need to get the result of the count(*)